# How are the Casimir operators of a real Lie algebra related to the Casimir operators of the complexification?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is a widespread convention in physics to define a basis on the Lie algebra of SU(d) with the matrices $E_{ij}:=|i\rangle\langle j|-\frac{1}{d}\delta_{ij}\mathrm{Id}$ when one constructs the Casimir operators. ($\{|i\rangle\}_{i=1}^d$ is an orthonormal basis on $\mathbb{C}^d$.) However, there is something fishy going on here: The (real) Lie algebra of SU(d) consists of traceless skew-hermitian matrices, and these basis elements are obviously not skew-hermitian. What is happening is that apparently, the Lie algebra got implicitly complexified on the way, and it turned into the Lie algebra of the det 1 subgroup of the general linear group. (This one probably has a name I should know.) The matrices $E_{ij}$ constitute a basis on this Lie algebra. My question is:

> Is it proper to do this when constructing the Casimir operators, and if so why? In general, how are the Casimir operators of a real Lie algebra related to the Casimir operators of the complexification?

My hunch is that the Casimir operators one gets with a basis of the Complexified Lie algebra are just the normal Casimir operators times some complex numbers, but I don't quite see how to prove that.